# Magento : Move Category Top Description to Bottom or Below Footer

Tags: magento-1.9, category

My category description appears just below the category title banner. I want to shift it to bottom of the page or even better below the footer as there will be a unique description for each category.

[image: Example for reference]

I tried the following approach of moving

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to the end of the file in `view.phtml` but that did not help.

Comment: can you tell me the path of view.phtml which you try to change?

Comment: The path is `app\design\frontend\[Your theme Path]\template\catalog\category\view.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

To move category description at end of the product list, you need to do this things.

1. Open category view file which is at this location.

   ```
   app\design\frontend\[Your theme Path]\template\catalog\category\view.phtml
   ```
2. Currently description is al arround line no. 56 code like

   ```
       <?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
       <div class="category-description std">
       <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
       </div>
       <?php endif; ?>
   ```
3. Remove this code from here and put this code at the end of the same file.
4. Do caching and indexing of magento from the admin.

Comment: I have tried this approach but the description still shows in the banner as well as at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Above same things working for me, Have you confirm have you change proper theme files?

Comment: No. There has been no changes made at all.